# Angular Material md-icon usage

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, google-material-icons

I am trying to use the md-icon in my app as per the documentation given [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdIcon). However I am only able to get working with the type of syntax:

```
<i class="material-icons ng-scope">search</i>
```

The other usage type

```
<md-icon md-font-icon="search" alt="search"></md-icon>
<md-icon md-font-icon="icon-magnify" class="icon"></md-icon>
```

does not load anything.

I have already loaded the material fonts with

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Though I can get the work done with the first syntax; I am interested to know what am I doing wrong that the second syntax is not working, while it should work perfectly as per the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not loading them inside the correct element,

Here is a sample,

```
  <md-button aria-label="Search" type="submit">
  <md-icon md-font-icon="search">search</md-icon> 
  </md-button>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/du561vz8/1/)**

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. As per the documentation here https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdIcon , <md-icon md-font-icon="search"></md-icon> should wok fine, however ,it's not displaying anything even in your demo. One needs to mention the classname search between tags <md-icon md-font-icon="search">search</md-icon> to make it work, which was my original question. Is there something wrong with <md-icon md-font-icon="search" alt="search"></md-icon> ?

Comment: Try this    <md-icon class="material-icons name" md-font-icon="search">search</md-icon>

Comment: just <md-icon>search</md-icon> woks fine too, but this refers to the first way of doing things like i mentioned in the question. I was trying to get the "Use <md-icon md-font-icon="classname" />" form working as mentioned in the documentation i shared. But that is not working for me. :(

Comment: can you show a sample on the documentation where it works like you mentioned